# How to return a Future<User> from function which returns User?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

How to return a Future from function which returns User?

```
final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

User getCurrentUser() {
  return auth.currentUser;
}
```

Now, in main.dart I need to deside is user authentificated and return a screen

```
home: FutureBuilder(
    future: AuthMethods().getCurrentUser(), ///////// error
    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<User> snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        return Home();
      } else {
        return SignIn();
      }
    },
),
```

The problem is `The argument type 'User' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future<User>'.`  So how to achive that scenario?

Comment: check existing `Future` class constructors

Comment: but actually, why would you want to use `FutureBuilder` if you already have the `User` value?

Comment: @pskink i.e. should I use somethinhg like this `home: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser !=null ? Home() : SignIn()` ?

Comment: There is absolutely no point in using a `FutureBuilder` here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm with Riwen here: why are you trying to use a `FutureBuilder` here?

While that was needed in older versions of the FlutterFire libraries, you're using a version of the library where `auth.currentUser` returns a value straight away, so you don't need a `FutureBuilder`.

So:

```
home: if (getCurrentUser() != null) {
        return Home();
      } else {
        return SignIn();
      }
    },
),
```

Or as a single ternary expression:

```
home: (getCurrentUser() != null) ? Home() : SignIn();
```

Answer (score 0):

You must return getCurrentUser as future:

```
Future<User> getCurrentUser() async {
  return auth.currentUser;
}
```